# Progress bar Indeterminado

Tags: android, progressbar

Tengo un problema, mi ProgressBar se visualiza bien pero esta estático osea sin ningún efecto y yo necesito que se mueva de forma aleatoria mientras se carga una pagina

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progreso"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68.5dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    />
```

que sera?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que eliminar la propiedad `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`. Esa propiedad es la que hace que el ProgressBar sea indeterminado.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progreso"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68.5dp"
    android:padding="0dp"/>
```

[Documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre solucionar, elimine la linea `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` y lo reemplaze por la linea `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progreso"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68.5dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    />
```